# Read System call and null-terminated character

Tags: c, system-calls

If I read from a file with a certain file descriptor using the `read()` system call into a `buffer`, does `read()` will add a null-terminated character in the `buffer`? Or do I need to implicitly include the null-terminated character in the file so that it will be added into the `buffer`?

Comment: Short answer (NO) `read()` is an unformatted read and cares nothing about c-string nul-termianting characters. It's just a `0` as far as `read()` is concerned. See [man 2 read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Comment: No to both questions.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not. `read()` handles binary files with can contain null characters.

Generally speaking, when processing text we just assume there aren't any null characters in it; but some programs actually process them. Both `read()` and `getc()` handle nulls just fine. It's the string libraries that aren't happy with them or lack of them.

So, no, don't pass your `read()` buffer to `strlen()`. You need to keep track of that yourself. The other basic `str*` functions typically have `mem*` functions that do the same thing where you pass the length of an argument. In particular, we have `memcpy(), memmem(), memchr()`. There's no `memcat()` but synthesis is trivial.

Comment: "we just assume there aren't any null characters in it" --> Good code does not make this unnecessary assumption.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Does good code include `scanf` and `fgets`?

Comment: Both `scanf()` and `fgets()` are challenging to use and detect _null characters_.  Good code and poor code use these functions - it depends on how they are used.